# Error in order(desc(var3), .by_group = TRUE) : argument lengths differ

Tags: r, dplyr

I get this error (**Error in order(desc(var3), .by_group = TRUE) :
argument lengths differ**) when I ran the code below. Any quick tip on how to solve this error?

```
df_final <- df_merged %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  arrange(desc(var3), .by_group = TRUE ) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_final <- df_merged %>%
  arrange(var1, var2, desc(var3)) %>%
 # group_by(whatever you want to group) %>% 
  slice(1L) # %>% 
 # ungroup()
```